# On Error GoTo a specific line outside loop then continue inside loop

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

[Excel view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1DtX.png)

I am trying to move folders to another folder (moving object).

I programmed an `On Error GoTo Error_Manager` to print the cell if there is an error.

```vb
Sub copy_paste_folder()
    Dim folder As Object
    Dim origin As String
    Dim destiny As String
    Set folder = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Dim start_range As Range
    Set start_range = ActiveSheet.Range("B2")

    start_range.Select

    On Error GoTo ErrorManager:

    'The loop begins, in the excel we will see origin and destiny route.
    Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
        origin = ActiveCell.Value
        ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1).Activate
        destiny = ActiveCell.Value
        ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=1, columnOffset:=-1).Activate
        folder.copyfolder origin, destiny
    Loop

    Exit Sub

'I want to print the cell in case of an error.

ErrorManager:  
    If Err.Number = 76 Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=-1, columnOffset:=-1).Activate
        ActiveCell.Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(255, 185, 185)
        ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=1, columnOffset:=1).Activate
    End If

End Sub
```

After finding an error, it begins again in `start_range.Select` and not in the loop. After the error it has to go to the loop.

Comment: In which line are you expecting the error to occur.

Comment: Hi @freeflow, thank you for the quick answer:
I expect the error in the line: "Origin = ActiveCell.Value"

Comment: Then the error return to a specific cell to paint it in red (where I write the reference folder), and move 1 row below, 1 column right (where I wrote the route folder), 

and should keep going again in "Origin = ActiveCell.Value"

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I expect the error in the line: "Origin = ActiveCell.Value".

If I understand your code correctly you have origin data in column B and destiny (destination?) data in column C.  If you annotate your code you can see that your offsets get a little confused.

```
'The loop begins, in the excel we will see origin and destiny route.
Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" 'C2
origin = ActiveCell.Value 'B2
ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1).Activate ' Activate C2
destiny = ActiveCell.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=1, columnOffset:=-1).Activate 'Activate B3
folder.copyfolder origin, destiny
Loop


Exit Sub


'In case of error

ErrorManager: 'I want to print the cell in case of error.
If Err.Number = 76 Then
ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=-1, columnOffset:=-1).Activate ' Activate A1
ActiveCell.Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(255, 185, 185)
ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=1, columnOffset:=1).Activate ' Activate B2
End If
```

In VBA life becomes much simple if you use ranges rather than the Activecell.  Its also helpful to try to isolate 'On Error' activites to their own function.

I hope the code below is closer to what you were trying to achieve.

```
Option Explicit


Sub copy_paste_folder()
    
    Const CurrentRow As Long = 0
    Const NextCol As Long = 1
    
    Dim origin As String
    Dim destiny As String
    
    Dim folder As Object
    Set folder = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    
   
    ' You can search for the first empty cell or just use an arbitrarly long range
    ' based on the offsets I'm assuming you have origin data in col B and destiny data in Col C
    Dim start_range As Range
    Set start_range = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B<theend>")

    ' I'm also a for each loop rather moving by activating a cell in the next row
    ' to make it the current cell.
    '
    Dim myCell As Variant
    For Each myCell In start_range.Cells
    
        ' The two lines below 'Cast' the variant myRange to the exact type we want to use.
        ' doing this cast means we get the advantage of intellisense when following myCurrentCell with a '.'
        Dim myCurrentCell As Excel.Range
        Set myCurrentCell = myCell
        
        ' presumably your are testing for "" to determine of the  cell is empty
        If IsEmpty(myCurrentCell) Then
        
            Exit For
    
        ' If there is no error then TryGetValue will be true and the value of myrange will be in origin.
        ElseIf TryGetValue(myCurrentCell, origin) Then
            
            destiny = myCurrentCell.Offset(CurrentRow, NextCol).Value
            folder.copyfolder origin, destiny
    
        Else ' if we get here there was an error

            myCurrentCell.Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(255, 185, 185)
            
        End If
        
    Next

End Sub

' The try function return true if the value was obtained without an error
' false if there was an error.
Public Function TryGetValue(ByRef ipRange As Excel.Range, ByRef opValue As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    opValue = ipRange.Value
    TryGetValue = Err.Number = 0
End Function
```

As I don't have your data I haven't tested the code above but it does compile without error.

Comment: Thank you very much! As I see in your comments, you guessed well where I had the origin and the destiny route. I will try it tomorrow at work, and I will let you know if it worked. :)

Comment: Hi again! I tried today the code, but I get an "error: 1004" in 
Set start_range = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B<theend>")

I think that's because in the Column be is the route to the folder. I think that if we write:
Dim start_range as integer can we solve that but I am not 100% sure. I will try to post up here in the question an image about how it looks the excel

Comment: Did you replace  the 'B<theend>' with a correct cell reference?

Comment: Hi @freeflow , I did and appears the error "Path not found". I am sorry to bother you again.